# Will squarespace appear in my url if I registered my domain name independently?

Tags: web-hosting

I registered a .com domain name with google domains, let's say jeremyradcliff.com, and am thinking of using squarespace as a host for a photography website.

I just want to make sure that even though squarespace will be hosting my website, my url will still just be jeremyradcliff.com and that squarespace will not appear anywhere in the url.

Also, will my website have to display "powered by squarespace" at the bottom of the homepage?

PS: I read their FAQ but as a total noob of anything web-hosting related, it's still not clear at all to me and I have to be absolutely sure of this before moving forward.

Comment: if I have answered your question please select it as the accepted answer to remove it from the unanswered questions list. If you have any additional query regarding this place a comment and I'll deal with it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will be possible, however you will need to pay Squarespace monthly for the appropriate service level. Also, they will require the delegation of the domain name to their DNS servers to achieve this.

This is the same with Squarespace branding - and is the same with any of these proprietary website-builder services.

If you inspect their various payment options this will be explained in detail.